# Some public wall posts missing in facebook api response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the facebook api to crawl post from one page wall. The post will be published by random facebook users. The posts are shown on a landingpage.

That work's very fine for the first dev tests. But since we have switch into a live version (now random user write posts) where are some posts that are not in the facebook api's response.

My first thought was that the privacy setting of the post is not public. But then I shouldn't see it when I am logout.

Why I didn't see that few posts? Have someone a tip?

```
$url =  '/' . $pageId . '/feed?fields=from, message, id, link, type, created_time, updated_time, shares, object_id,comments.limit(1).summary(true),likes.limit(1).summary(true)&since=' . $since;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `&filter=stream` to your call.

Facebook will defaults to a "Top Story" feed which can hide some objects due to a low "score".  This will force the return to be in a "Most Recent" style feed where all objects will be shown and in chronological order.

Comment: This don't affect my result.

But intresting information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My Idea:  Some posts are missing in the api because of the privacy setting of facebook user? Maybe because the profile is not visible for non-facebook users? The publicity of the posts on facebook wall is always public when i look at the facebook wall. Have somebody experience with that?